# Python/Pandas - How can I keep ONLY the parent dataframe of an outer join?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

The actual data has a bit more fields, less on df1 and more on df2. Some columns have slightly different names.

```
# intialise data of lists.
data1 = {'NameA':['Tom', 'Nick', 'Krish', 'Jack'],
        'AgeA':[20, 21, 19, 18]}
data2 = {'NameB':['Tom', 'Nick', 'C', 'D'],
        'AgeB':[20, 21, 3, 4]}

# Create DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
list = [df1, df2]

df1 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',left_on=['NameA','AgeA'],right_on=['NameB','AgeB'])
print(df1)
```

Output =

```
   NameA  AgeA NameB  AgeB
0    Tom    20   Tom  20.0
1   Nick    21  Nick  21.0
2  Krish    19   NaN   NaN
3   Jack    18   NaN   NaN
```

Expected =

[image: Using Alteryx join and getting left join output]

I'm having trouble achieving the left join leaving only the parent table behind with Pandas/Python. Does anyone have some pointers? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with `left join` and parameter `indicator` in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',left_on=['NameA','AgeA'],right_on=['NameB','AgeB'], indicator=True)
print(df3)
   NameA  AgeA NameB  AgeB     _merge
0    Tom    20   Tom  20.0       both
1   Nick    21  Nick  21.0       both
2  Krish    19   NaN   NaN  left_only
3   Jack    18   NaN   NaN  left_only

df = df3.loc[df3['_merge'].eq('left_only'), df1.columns]
print (df)
   NameA  AgeA
2  Krish    19
3   Jack    18
```

Solution with outer join:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',left_on=['NameA','AgeA'],right_on=['NameB','AgeB'], indicator=True)
print(df3)
   NameA  AgeA NameB  AgeB      _merge
0    Tom  20.0   Tom  20.0        both
1   Nick  21.0  Nick  21.0        both
2  Krish  19.0   NaN   NaN   left_only
3   Jack  18.0   NaN   NaN   left_only
4    NaN   NaN     C   3.0  right_only
5    NaN   NaN     D   4.0  right_only

df = df3.loc[df3['_merge'].eq('left_only'), df1.columns]
print (df)
   NameA  AgeA
2  Krish  19.0
3   Jack  18.0
```

Comment: Ah, I meant left outer join but you got the gist of the question. Thank you!

Comment: @Anonymous - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)